# It looks like the first console.log isn't quite right

Tags: javascript

CODING IS JAVASCRIPT THROUGH CODECADEMY.COM
got an error :

```
  {if (
    14 % 3 == 2 )
  {
    console.log("The answer is true");  
}`
```

the code is executed but error message pops up saying "it looks like the first console.log isnt quite right.

Comment: Correct your syntax, and avoid multiple lines in your `if` conditions

Comment: I count two `{` but only one `}`. Don't you find that odd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invalid syntax in your code. Plz correct your code:

```
if (14 % 3 == 2 ) {
    console.log("The answer is true");
}
```

Read more about `if` at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)